# How do I turn off location permanently on Android

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, gps-tracking

My Samsung note 8 is running Android 9.

GPS location is frequently turned on without my knowledge or permission. There appear to be multiple triggers for this including a change in Wifi network e.g. leaving the house using cellular data and coming back.

This is a nuisance and unwarranted location tracking of the phone. I want to be in control of when I decide to use location based services.

Is there a way of switching off location globally in the settings so I can control this behaviour?

Comment: In regular Android devices with Android 9 you can see in system settings location you should be able to see the last apps that have requested your location and it's granularity (GPS or Wifi/Mobile network position). Not sure if this menu has survived Samsung's modifications.